# Как ограничить zabbix-агент для обнаружения из внешней сети?

Tags: linux, администрирование, zabbix, firewall

Планирую мониторить железный сервер с помощью zabbix. Сам сервер zabbix'а будет внутри виртуальной машины на этом же сервере. Как мне сделать так, чтобы все, кто сканировал мой белый ip не видели, что у меня открыт порт агента? В интернете советуют или поменять порт на нестандартный или не париться, потому что в настройках указан адрес сервера, а значит остальные запросы будут дропаться. Но всё это звучит как полумеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

положи забикс в виртуальную изолированную подсетку. на агенте в конфиге ListenIP поставь адрес из этой подсети.

Comment: Т.е. создать виртуальный адаптер, дать ему доступ к виртуалке заббикс-сервака и уже привязывать этот ip в агенте? Я ничего не перепутал?

Answer (score 0):

Дополню [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1529514/191416) [@eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16574/eri) конечной реализацией, которая у меня заработала в тестовой среде.

Использовал `netplan`:

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

```yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses:
        - 10.100.1.38/24:
            label: "eth0:zbx-ag"
```

Тестим/применяем конфиг:
`sudo netplan try`

В итоге, выхлоп примерно такой:

`sudo ifconfig`

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet <внешний ip>  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast <внешний бродкаст>
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe46:b2e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:46:0b:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 118851  bytes 171228788 (171.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 67800  bytes 9228459 (9.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0:zbx-ag: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.100.1.38  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.100.1.255
        ether 08:00:27:46:0b:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Локальная петля (Loopback))
        RX packets 128645  bytes 163302207 (163.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 128645  bytes 163302207 (163.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Меняем настройки zabbix агента:

```bash
sudo sed -i 's/ListenIP=127.0.0.1/ListenIP=10.100.1.38/' /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent2.conf
```

Перезапускаем:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart zabbix-agent2.service
```

PROFIT!!!

[image: Zabbix-агент видится сервером]

Сканирование с другого компьютера внешнего ip будет выглядеть так:

```bash
nmap <внешний ip> -p10050
```

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-07-09 11:29 UTC
Nmap scan report for <внешний ip>
Host is up (0.00033s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE
10050/tcp closed zabbix-agent
```

[Источник](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-use-multiple-addresses-on-a-single-interface).

Comment: Да, в случае докера внутренняя сеть, в другом случае может быть другая сеть. Сама суть - забиндить заббикс только к внутреннему адресу